# Switch to Python 3.x in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

By default Spyder uses Python 2.7.2, and my question is: is there a way to set up Spyder so that it automatically uses Python 3.x? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time this question was asked, Python 3 was not supported by Spyder (and this answer said so, giving some details of the then-incomplete porting efforts).

But that's not the case any longer! Recent builds of Spyder should work with Python 3. Check out the other answers for some links to places to get it from (though they may be out of date themselves by this point).

Answer (score 18):

Since end of May 2013, version v2.3.0dev1 of Spyder works for **Python 3.3 and above**.
It is in a usable state but there are a few minor problems.
Hopefully they will be resolved soon.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 13.10.  From their [download page](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads), I installed v2.3.0beta3.zip (which was the latest as of 8 Feb, 2014.  I unzipped it, opened the folder and ran `python3 setup.py install`.  I also had to do `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4` before running Spyder.

Comment: Upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 caused it to stop working.  So I followed my previous comment and it now works on 14.04 also.

Comment: BTW, if you have `checkinstall` (sudo apt-get install checkinstall), then it's better to do `sudo checkinstall python3 setup.py install`, because then you can easily remove it with `dpkg -r spyder`.

Answer (score 14):

To use Spyder for Python 3, you just need v2.3.0 or later.

**Ubuntu 12.10 and later**

You can get this by using `pip3`.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-pyqt4
sudo pip3 install spyder
```

**Ubuntu 12.04**

Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have `python3-pip` in the repositories, but you can get it with `setuptools`,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4 python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo pip3 install spyder
```

you can then open Spyder from the launcher (after logging out and in) or from the terminal by typing `spyder3`.

Answer (score 8):

**Ubuntu 16.04**

Garrett's solution did not work for me. Pip is installed, but running the "install spyder" command does not install spyder using Python3.5. I uninstalled spyder.

What worked was simply:

```
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```

This will also automatically install any Python 3.x dependencies.

Comment: I just tried installing this. Installation worked, but I can't successfully run it. I get an error "The application Spyder3 has closed unexpectedly"

Comment: I assume python is installed? Sounds like an unrelated problem.

Comment: python and python3 are indeed installed.  Do you have any other advice?  I suppose I will file a bug report.

Comment: Yeah I definitely did lots of googling.  I had better luck with pip3 install spyder.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 14.04 I found spyder3 at official repository

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:
Use Anaconda to manage your scientific software.
There is an installer specifically for Python 3.5
https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: They don't offer installer for ARM( a.k.a `aarch64` or `armhf`) architecture though, which my Chromebook has.